# Susy Next content source ordered layout

Tags: css, grid, sass, susy-compass

I'm having a few issues understanding how to produce the following layout using Susy Next.

While this is pretty strait forward with strait CSS I can't seem to get my head around doing this cleanly in Susy, or at all really.

A caveat here is that I can't add any extra wrappers into the layout, it's just four DIV blocks and has to be that way. The other caveat is that I would really prefer to be using Susy Next (I am using alpha4 at the moment).

Really kind of hoping I am just not seeing the woods for the tress as I have only been using Susy for a few weeks.

The source order is:

```
first
second
third
fourth
```

The required layout is:

```
    -----------------------------------------
   |  fourth    |           first            |
   |             ----------------------------
   |            |    second   |     third    |
    -----------------------------------------
```

### Update 1.

Update to add my current CSS solution, I've included the markup and all the CSS taking affect on the page, for completeness:

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="region region-first"></div>
    <div class="region region-second"></div>
    <div class="region region-third"></div>
    <div class="region region-fourth"></div>
  </div>
</main>

.container {
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 73.75em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 1.25em;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main .region:first-child {
  width: 66.1016949%;
  float: right;
}
main .region:nth-child(2) {
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 33.8983051%;
  width: 32.2033898%;
}
main .region:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: -66.1016949%;
  width: 32.2033898%;
  float: right;
}
main .region:last-child {
  width: 32.2033898%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

### Some Ideas for a Solution?

I started to poke the internals of Susy Next and tried called the span() function directly to just get widths, hooray this works where I just need a value for width: , however...

...where I am doing `margin-right: span(4 + $gutter)` the margin-right value needs to be the same value as push or pre would return, but I can't quite understand all the internals of how they work, my "magical float" of .75 when calculating $gutter is ever so slightly inaccurate, it might be right, but of course change a value in set-grid and it can be wrong, so its a rough guess at best.

What I need is a way to get the same value as pre would return, but of course just the value OR just a whole better way of doing the whole thing :)

```
.region {

  &:first-child {
    @include span(8 omega of 12);
  }

  &:nth-child(2) {
    $gutter: $gutters * .75;
    margin-right: span(4 + $gutter);
    width: span(4);
    float: right;
    clear: right;
  }

  &:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: - span(8);
    width: span(4);
    float: right;
  }

  &:last-child {
    width: span(4);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually straight-forward in CSS. I've never seen it done without some complexity, set-heights, or JS. Anything you can do in CSS is possible with Susy. If you show me a CSS solution, I'll show you how to create it with Susy. :)

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible with pure CSS.  This can only be done with floats and the source order must be 4, 1, 2, 3.  Flexbox would allow you to reorder, but you won't be able to get this layout at all (4 and 1 in one row, 2 and 3 in the next row).

Comment: Wow quick guys, ok I updated my post to include the CSS and markup that I hand crafted to prototype the layout - you are right that perhaps its not that strait forward :) @cimmanon, yeah, it is possible, perhaps I am not explaining it right, I tried to add an image but I don't have enough street cred yet :) I can take a screenshot of the browser and post it somewhere if you want, I found it hard to explain what I mean and my ascii art is not great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - it's totally possible and not even very hard in Susy Next:

```
.region {
  &:first-child { @include span(last 8); }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    clear: right;
    @include span(4 at 5 isolate);
  }
  &:nth-child(3) { @include span(last 4 isolate); }
  &:last-child { width: span(4); }
}
```

The `isolation` option allows you to position elements at specific locations on the grid.

Comment: Yes! That's brilliant Eric, and completely opens my eyes on Susy Next and how I can and should be using it. Thank-you so much for taking the time to answer my question, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. You will need to read through the original question as to why this is an answer - essentially what it comes down to is the right tool for the job. I was trying to solve my problem using Susy mixins (initially), however turning to Susy functions helped get me most of the way to a solution.

The final part is to write my own function to return the right value that I needed for the nth-child(2) div, it needs a margin-right to push it back into position the correct amount. Copying the internals of the Susy pre mixin was the obvious course of action here, and it worked, hooray!

```
@function elf-margin-value(
  $span,
  $columns
) {
  $this: $span, $columns;
  $value: if(index($this, outer), $this, append($this, outer));
  @return span($value);
}
```

So in my code I can use it like this:

```
margin-right: elf-margin-value(4, 12);
```

Minor issue - I know what index and append are doing, but not I'm not quite sure about outer.

Not the place to discuss but I wonder if this abstraction would be good for Susy Next, rather than baking this same/similar logic into several mixins. I would benefit at least :)

Anyway this is how I solved this for now, I am still very interested to hear if Eric has some advice for this and if my solution can be done easier/better.

The solution thus far is the following:

```
$to: to($flow);
.region {

  &:first-child {
    @include span(8 omega of 12);
  }

  &:nth-child(2) {
    margin-#{$to}: elf-margin-value(4, 12);
    width: span(4);
    float: $to;
    clear: $to;
  }

  &:nth-child(3) {
    margin-#{$to}: - span(8);
    width: span(4);
    float: $to;
  }

  &:last-child {
    width: span(4);
  }
}
```